# The command could not be located because ‘/bin:/usr/bin’ is not included in the PATH environment variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I got this error message when restarting my ubuntu laptop. I went into a login loop, and so I pressed
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

To access terminal, which I did, but I experienced this error:

```
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
 * /bin/lesspipe
 * /usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

I temporarily fix this error running below command, but when I open again, this error is again coming, I again running below command.

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:$PATH"
```

But when I comeback to login, it still fails with same error. Any help to resolve this?
I am on ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

echo $PATH returns

```
-bash: /home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:...: no such file or directory
```

Comment: @GerardH.Pille It is part of a Unix path export. Did you skip some steps in your Linux training?

Comment: @DavidPostill It wasn't part of en export when I posted my comment.  Perhaps you should have a look at the edit history, if you have the time.  If you believe an "echo $PATH" would return "no such file", well, ...